# How to encode a not equal to operator to filter a URL? Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, asp.net-web-api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to filter out some values from a Web API and I am encoding my requests into python dictionaries to avoid receiving the complete data set from the URL, however, I want to implement a **not equal operator** where purchase is not equal to pets. How can I do that?

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from collections import Counter
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json, urllib.request, dateutil.parser, urllib.parse


url = "http://10.61.202.98:8081/T/ansdb/api/rows/dev/data/tickets"

    #not equal to parameter should be applied here
    parameters = {'user': 'P. J.', 'purchase':'pets'}

    encoded_parameters = urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters)
    encoded_parameters = encoded_parameters.encode('utf-8')
    make_request = urllib.request.Request(url,encoded_parameters)

    with urllib.request.urlopen(make_request, timeout=15) as url:
        complete_data_user = json.loads(url.read().decode())
```

Comment: I'm unclear on what you are asking. Can you clarify?